# How do i Intent to Device administrators

Tags: android, android-intent

i want a button in my application which will redirect user to Device administrators window

and i think there is a way via Intent

[image: ScreenShot]

**Already tried**

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
                                    mDPM.removeActiveAdmin(cn);
```

Comment: What have you tried? What have you tried searching even? As it stands now this question is little more than a vague request for someone to just provide you with research time.

Comment: sorry, check the update